# Django rest-framework howto serialize a object/foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with Django Rest Framework.
I have the follow codes:

serializers.py

```
class TextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Text
        fields = ('title', 'project', 'content')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Text.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt        
def text_view_set(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = TextSerializer(data=data)
        # How to put project in serializer to is_valid() return True?
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my_command.py

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
        text = u'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, deseruisse voluptatum est cu, ea elit tation delicatissimi per. Decore soleat pri at.'
        url = u'http://localhost:8080/text/4/'

        params = { 'title' : u'Hello World', 'content': text.encode('utf8'), }
        req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(params), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

So, the result is a bad request error (400), because the is_valid() method return False. That's OK. The field 'project' is not in data object serialized.

But, how can I insert this value in View or Model method? 
I don't want to pass this value (project) in params, because it's already in URL:

```
        url = u'http://localhost:8080/text/4/'
```

Comment: Why don't you map 'url' to a HyperlinkedRelatedField pointing at the relation (using 'source')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like..

```
data = JSONParser().parse(request)
data.update({'pk': project_id})
```

Comment: Great! This work for me!  `data.update({'project': project_id})`